# Is it possible to build 3 or more concentric circles / nested circles / telescoping pieces?

Tags: building, compatibility, design

There are round 2x2 pieces.
There are round 4x4 pieces with round 2x2 holes, the 2x2 can slide/rotate inside of it.
There are "macaroni" pieces to make an 8x8 circle with a 6x6 hole.
But are there no 6x6 rounds with a 4x4 hole?

I've also seen sets use curved slopes, curved inverted slopes, and arches to make circles or nearly-perfect-circles. Are there ways to make nested circles from those pieces?

Comment: It is a bit difficult to see what you are aiming at. From what I read, you are looking for concentric brick circles or tubes that fit into each other? Maybe like a telescope? There are arches that can achieve sort of concentric 180 degrees, but it sounds as if you are looking for something else. Have you checked the "arch" or "cylinder" sections in bricklink?

Comment: I can also suggest to look into curved slopes. These + SNOT techniques may bring shape close to circle.

Comment: Aziraphale I'm asking for either: telescope of bricks or even flat plate circles that nest together with no gaps. I looked at cylinder pieces and they seem to have the same dimensions, there is no 6x6 round with a 4x4 round hole. Though I did see one with a square 2x2 hole, that could be helpful, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: But why are you asking for that? I.e. what do you want to build? If you told us maybe we could suggest some other way of achieving your goal.

Comment: What about [30554b](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=30554b#T=A) you can use 8 of those to make a ring around a 4x4 circle, which is done in set 21309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one piece that fits all your criteria: [41823](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=41823&name=Fence%203%20x%203%20x%202%20Quarter%20Round%20Ornate%20with%202%20Studs&category=%5BFence%5D#T=S&C=115&O=%7B%22color%22:115,%22iconly%22:0%7D). Placing four of those pieces together will create a 6x6 circle with a 4x4 interior gap. Albeit, it is a decorative fence piece and it's two studs tall, so it might not work for what you are trying to accomplish.